# Configuring the build path for Eclipse projects

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I have two projects in Eclipse referencing `org.eclipse.swt` do I need to configure the build path for both of them, or can I do this on a workspace basis ?

I can't find a way to do this for a workspace, but if it doesn't exist this means I have to configure the build path for each of my projects where I know they all use `org.eclipse.swt`.

Comment: What sort of project? Are they plugins or normal Java programs that use SWT.

Comment: normal java projects.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to create a project that has SWT on the classpath and then add this to all other projects. Make sure you export the dependencies (there is an extra tab for that); that will make them visible in all other projects as well.

Over time, you will find that this setup also allows you to add helper code in this project which can then also be shared with all other projects.